# What expression could allow a tuple with NULL attribute to pass

Tags: sql

For common expression like a + b > 5, it is obvious that as long as b or a is NULL, the the expression would not be true. In other words, the the null attribute could not pass this expression.

However, expression like `coalesce` could allow a tuple with NULL attribute to pass. For example, `coalesce(a,b) > 0`, even if a is NULL, as long as b > 0, then this tuple could still pass.

My question is that except `coalesce`, is there any other common expression could allow a tuple with null attribute to possibly pass the condition test?

Comment: Another example would be `ISNULL(a,0) + b > 5`

Comment: Using `ISNULL`, `COALESCE` in your `WHERE`, however, is not a good idea; it'll ruin the SARGability of your query. Use proper `NULL` logic if you are handling `NULL`s

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 very different RDBMS here?

Comment: Just answering your question, yes there are other ways you can do that. But the real question here is what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server <> Postgresql.

Comment: You seem to have a problem that you *think* will be solved by identifying language constructs that perform special null handling. Maybe it will, maybe it won't. Wouldn't it be better to ask a question *about* that problem though, rather than your proposed solution?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I ask about "common expression" since I don't really work on a specific RDBMS, I believe coalesce have the identical behaviour across these platforms and that is why I tag these databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some standard expressions that pass for `NULL` values:

```
a is not null
a is distinct from 1
coalesce(a, 1) > 0
(case when a > 0 then 1 when a is null then 1 else 0 end)
a || 'abc' = 'abc'
```

Some databases have synonyms for `coalesce()`-like functionality -- `nz()`, `ifnull()`, `nvl()` come to mind.